# How to fix this error:Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.arrdata.map is not a function

Tags: api, reactjs, reactjs-flux

How to fix this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.arrdata.map is not a function

I am learning React and I hope you can help me. Thanks!

[image: List.jsx]

[image: httpservice.js]

Comment: have you tried googling the error?

Comment: You will get a much better response from others willing to help you if you do **_not_** post a screenshot of your code.  Copy the text of your code, edit this question, and paste in the code.  Use the Markdown formatting to indicate that the text is code, which may activate syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AlexKhue You also published your api key in your screenshot, not really a big deal in this case but I would make sure to remove that from screenshots /posts in the future.

Answer (score 1):

OpenWeatherMap's API [does not return an array, but an object](https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON).

Objects do not have a `map()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using lodash.map because it doesn't care if it's undefined, object or array which could save a lot of trouble.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

var listItems = _.map(this.state.arrData, (function(item){
   ... bla bla bla
})
```